# javascript String to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string:

```
a = "{u'a':[u'123',u'321'], u'b':[u'456',u'654']}"
```

I want to convert this *a* to a json data.

How to do it?

I have tried JSON.parse(), but it will raise an error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

Comment: Isn't that obvious? What is that `u` before the single quotes? `u'a'`, `u'b'`, etc.? `a = "{'a':['123','321'], 'b':['456','654']}";`

Comment: What is u ? a variable ?

Comment: @Dilantha: It's the prefix for a [Python `unicode` literal](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can just replace each `u'x'` with `"x"` and you'll have valid JSON:

```
var a = "{u'a':[u'123',u'321'], u'b':[u'456',u'654']}";

// Convert to JSON (May not work with other inputs!)
var json = a.replace(/u'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'/g, function(a,str){
  return '"' + str.replace(/\\'/g, '\'').replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"'; 
});

// Parse the JSON into a Javascript object
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Updated to work with some quotes in the object:

```
var a = "{u'a':[u'\\'123\\'',u'321'], u'b':[u'456\\\\',u'\"654\"']}";
```

Becomes:

```
{a:["'123'","321"], b:["456\",""654""]}
```

Comment: will not work if the strings contain unescaped double quotes, specifically

Comment: yes I have tried to do it. Like @jandvorak said how to handle single or double quotes?

Comment: @meshuai Can you show in your question what an example looks like with quotes in it?

Comment: Umm... one more thing: you need to escape double quotes. I'd use replace-with-callback for that

Comment: I said "escape double quotes", not "unescape single quotes". Though the latter needs to be done as well (sorry).

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, tested it works fine if a string ends in a backslash, see my edit (`u'456\\\\'`), which gets parsed by Javascript once, so it's just `u'456\\'` that gets converted to `"456\\"` in the JSON

Comment: Good job. I can't think of any cases where this would break :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks! You helped me find some of the edge cases :)

Comment: @Paulpro thx. So far so good. If I have other questions, I will ask you. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like Python literal syntax to me. Tell whoever wrote the Python portion to encode as JSON instead of just outputting the structure as a string.

Comment: Yes. This is the best way. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your input string to a valid JSON string.

I think this is what you wanted:

`JSON.parse('{"a":["123","321"], "b":["456","654"]}')`

Answer (score -1):

JSON is supposed to contain only strings.

`a = "{u'a':[u'123',u'321'], u'b':[u'456',u'654']}"`

Here I can only assume that `u` is a variable. Change it to this:

`a = "{"+u+"'a':["+u+"'123',"+u+"'321'], "+u+"'b':["+u+"'456',"+u+"'654']}"`

Comment: Interesting you thought that. I assumed it was a string prefix and should have been omitted.

Comment: Its possible. A prefix can be included in the string. Only reason not to would be if it was a variable.

Comment: Even if your interpretation was correct, `a` is still not valid JSON. It's not even valid Javascript code

Comment: now it's just that your interpretation is incorrect ;-) See the other answers as well as question comments. Concatenating a variable to all JSON keys hardly makes any sense. Also, is there any value of `u` (except `""`) that produces a valid JSON?

Comment: Yeah I did read them, but this is what I thought when I first saw it.

Answer (score -1):

The variables (keys / values ) are strings so need to be in quotes in order to be parsed as valid JSON.

// put quotes around the key / value pairs.

```
var a = "{\"u'a'\":[\"u'123'\",\"u'321'\"], \"u'b'\":[\"u'456'\",\"u'654'\"]}";
```

**jQuery**

```
a = $.parseJSON(a);
```

Comment: how? If "by the server", why? Why not output the correct JSON right away?

Comment: also, why use `$.parseJSON` instead of `JSON.parse`? [Do you need to support IE7?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON) More importantly, who said jQuery was available?

Comment: @JanDvorak To your first question, you need to ask the OP this. I just hinted that the key/value pairs need to be in quotes. On the second question, will you use `eval` instead?? If not jquery, you will need to use `json.js`. Take your pick. I don't want to answer some of the rhetorical questions, it's a matter of choice, mine not necessarily be the same as yours.

Comment: my point is that OP did _not_ say he needed IE7 support, and _he did not say he was using jQuery_. By the way, guess what jQuery uses as a fallback? ;-)

Comment: yes, it does. A matter of habit, i guess. your points are valid though.